# Add swipe function on my off-canvas menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a off canvas menu on my mobile HTML site.

[**DEMO**](http://codepen.io/ncerminara/pen/quJpi)

Its working good but slide effect working on just toggle-button. But I need swipe function on the menu.
How can I add it?

JS:

```
$(function() {

    // Toggle Nav on Click
    $('.toggle-nav').click(function() {
        // Calling a function in case you want to expand upon this.
        toggleNav();
    });


});

function toggleNav() {
    if ($('#site-wrapper').hasClass('show-nav')) {
        // Do things on Nav Close
        $('#site-wrapper').removeClass('show-nav');
    } else {
        // Do things on Nav Open
        $('#site-wrapper').addClass('show-nav');
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply listen to the `swipe` event

```
$("#site-canvas").on("swipe", function() {
    toggleNav();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using jQuery you can take advantage of the jQuery swipe event 
handler.

`$(window).on("swipe", function(event){ ... })`.

[Docs here.](https://api.jquerymobile.com/swipe/)